# Unwanted delay on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm facing a rather peculiar issue with one of my iOS obj-c projects that I can't wrap my head around. I'm starting an AVCaptureSession and setting an observer to watch the isRunning property. The observer then dispatches to the main thread and enables a UIButton...but even though the observer is called immediately when the session starts running the task on the main thread is sometimes delayed by 9-10seconds and on occasions it is triggered immediately. 
Here's the part of the code:

```
   -(void)addObservers {
    [self.session addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"running" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString: @"running"]) {
        NSLog(@"CaptureSession is running");

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.takePictureButton.enabled = self.session.isRunning;
            NSLog(@"Button is enabled: %i", self.session.isRunning);

        });
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
2018-06-15 10:45:41.126595+0200 Scan[699:81561] CaptureSession is running
2018-06-15 10:45:50.141507+0200 Scan[699:81541] Button is enabled: 1
```

I appreciate any suggestions. I can fix this with a different approach, but I'd like to understand what might be causing such behaviour.

Comment: @andras-m : Isnt KVO directly triggered on main thread in this case? Dont u think thread switching is unnecessary here ? Can u confirm

Comment: KVO is triggered on a different thread, it is the same thread that the session runs on (a custom serial thread)

Comment: How do you create the custom queue? What priority/class of service is it?

Comment: It's created with the following line 
`self.sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("sessionQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);`
The funny thing is now I started researching and found an example from Apple that is doing pretty much the same thing, so I don't know what is going on, or how I could debug it because when I run the profiler there's nothing that takes a long time to run, all seems to be running ok.